# Magento Customer Account Sharing across multiple websites

Tags: magento

I have a single magento installation **(ver 1.6)** and created 3 websites for USA, UK and Europe each has its own store and store view I want to implement multi-currency and sharing one shopping cart among all these three websites. Everything is fine but when I select

> System>Configuration>Default>Customer Configuration>Share Customer
>   Accounts to **Global**

, I get the following error after successful login tries to redirect customer

**Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in /home/wwwabc/public_html/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 293**

Sometimes login successfully redirect to My Account page and this error displayed when customer clicks on "Logout" I think there is some session/cookie issue but could not figure it out.

Anyone can help quickly please...?

Answer (score 0):

are u sharing cart on website level or store levels. Default magento share shopping cart on store view levels?

Comment: I am sharing cart on website level because I need to setup different based currencies for transactions.